# How to use eslint-config-stylelint

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, eslint, stylelint

css:

```
.fontSize11{ font-size: calc(var(--font-scale, 1 ) * 11px); }
```

In our project, we are using the above format for font-size in CSS. Some people in our team are not following the above format. To keep consistency someone suggested me to use eslint-config-stylelint to create a custom rule so it can be caught during development. I don't have experience with build tools and linters. I'll appreciate if someone can help me with it. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want people to only use `.fontSizeXX` classes or that they can use `font-size` but its value must be in the `calc(var(--font-size, 1) * XXpx)` form?

Comment: My key question is why are you using an ESLint shared config to lint CSS? 

You should be using either of these: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard

Comment: @jeddy3 I want people to use `calc(var(--font-size, 1) * XXpx)` form only for font size values in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stylelint's built-in [`declaration-property-value-allowed-list`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-property-value-allowed-list/) rule to enforce a specific pattern for the value of a property, rather than create a custom rule.

By using an regular expression, you can ensure that the value of the `font-size` property matches the `calc(var(--font-size, 1) * XXpx)` pattern:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "declaration-property-value-allowed-list": {
      "font-size": ["/calc\\(var\\(--font-scale, 1\\) \\* \\d+px\\)/"]
    }
  }
}
```

(There may be a cleaner way to write that regular expression.)

If you're just getting started with Stylelint, you'll want to extend [official standard config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard) in your config. Your complete Stylelint configuration should look like:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "rules": {
    "declaration-property-value-allowed-list": {
      "font-size": ["/calc\\(var\\(--font-scale, 1\\) \\* \\d+px\\)/"]
    }
  }
}
```

> To keep consistency someone suggested me to use eslint-config-stylelint to create a custom rule

Stylelint and ESLint are different tools. You should use:

- Stylelint to lint your CSS
- ESLint to lint your JavaScript

(`eslint-config-stylelint` is an internal package used by the Stylelint team to lint their JavaScript code. It's not intended for public consumption.)

Comment: how do I make the regex work for 11px and above only?